# Can the spells used to bind elementals in Eberron's airships/galleons/etc be dispelled?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron

Many of the descriptions of the magical forms of transport in the Eberron (v3.5) campaign setting (e.g. airships, galleons, lightning rails) speak of bound elementals as the source of propulsion for the transport.  My question is two-fold.  First, what spells (specifically) would be used to bind these elementals? Second, would it be possible to free/destroy/dismiss these elementals, and if so, which counterspell would be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the *Eberron Campaign Setting* p267, airships, galleons and the lightning rail require the spell *[greater planar binding](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/planarBindingGreater.htm)*, along with the feat Bind Elemental (*Eberron Campaign Setting* p51).

The spells *[dismissal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dismissal.htm)* and *[banishment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/banishment.htm)* can dismiss an extraplanar elemental. Both spells have a range of Close and target the elemental itself, so you'd need line of sight to the Khyber dragonshard that contains the elemental—you can't just hit an airship from the ground.

As airships, etc., are essentially giant magic items, *[dispel magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm)* would only suppress the vehicle for 1d4 rounds, but would not free the elemental, as the spell *greater planar binding* is instantaneous and not itself subject to *dispel magic* or *antimagic field*.

It's not stated anywhere what happens if the dragonshard is broken, but a reasonable ruling would be that it works like *[trap the soul](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/trapTheSoul.htm)*, which frees the creature if the gem is broken.

Comment: I just wonder what your take is on the description in the "Binding" spell that says "A bound extraplanar creature cannot be sent back to its home plane due to dismissal, banishment, or a similar effect"  Is the "Binding" spell related to the planar binding spell, and if so, does that negate your statement about dismissing?

Comment: What does the Bind Elemental feat actually do?  Is it something like an item creation feat?  Also, to use *dispel magic* you need a CL for the ship.

Comment: The feat description states "Crafting an item with a bound elemental is similar to making a wondrous item, except that calling and binding an elemental is an integral part of creating the item."  Don't know if this helps ...

Comment: @Cat _Binding_ is a mind-affecting compulsion of the enchantment school that affects one living creature within close range, whereas _planar binding_ is a conjuration which calls an extraplanar being. _Planar binding_ specifically says it doesn't block escape by dimensional travel, so it probably doesn't block _dismissal_ like _binding_ does.

Comment: @JonathanDrain Thanks - this was the piece I was missing :)

Comment: @starwed Bind Elemental is an item creation feat, yes. It's required for elemental-bound items, including airships, lightning rail, and certain magical weapons and armour.